# PowerShell += on foreach loop duplicates previously added data

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-excel

So i have an excel file like this

Document Number, Qty, Price

1111-01,1,3.00

1112-00A,2,4.00

And what I am doing is importing it into powershell, the going line by line.
If the quantity is ever greater than 1, I have to duplicate that line that many times whlie changing the quantity to 1 each time and updateing the document number so its unique on each line. I am then adding to an array so i can at the very end export as an excel file.

```
$report = Import-Excel "pathToFile.xlsx"
$report2 = @()
foreach($line in $report){
    $report2+=$line.PSObject.Copy()
}
$template = @()
foreach($line in $report2)
...
some irrelevant code
...
if($line.Qty -gt 1){
            $line2 = $line.PSObject.Copy()
            $ogInvoice = $line2.'Document Number'.Split("-")[0]
            $invoiceAfter = $line2.'Document Number'.Split("-")[1]
            if($invoiceAfter -match "^*[A-Z]$"){
                $letter = $invoiceAfter.Substring($invoiceAfter.Length-1,1)
                
            }else{
                $letter = ""
            }
            $qty = $line2.Qty
            $line2.Qty = 1
            $counterQty = 0
            while($counterQty -lt $qty){
                
                $invoiceLastTwoNumber = [int]('{0:d2}' -f[int] $invoiceAfter.Substring(0,2)) + $counter
                $line2.'Document Number' = (-join($ogInvoice,"-",$invoiceLastTwoNumber.ToString(),$letter))
                $counter = $counter + 1
                $template+=$line2
                $counterQty = $counterQty + 1
            }
}
```

The problem is that after checking the progress, the first time i add the line, the document number is 1112-50A like it should be, then the next time I add the line into $template, the document number is 1112-51A but it updates the previously added line.
So i get

1111-01,1,3.00

1112-51A,1,4.00

1112-51A,1,4.00

Instead of what i want which is:

1111-01,1,3.00

1112-50A,1,4.00

1112-51A,1,4.00

NOTE: the extra coding like PSObject.Copy is other stuff i found online because apparently iterating over the $report is more like a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to repeat the current object **as many times as `.Qty`** only if **`.Qty` is greater than 1** and in addition, update the **property Value to 1**.

In addition, seems like you're looking to increment the **last digits** of the property values of `Document Number`.

Leaving aside the extra code you are currently showing us and focusing only on the question being asked, this is how you could accomplish it, using `$csv` as an example of your source data.

```bash
$csv = @'
Document Number,Qty,Price
1111-01,1,3.00
1112-00A,2,4.00
1113-15A,4,5.00
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$re = [regex] '(\d+)(?=[A-Z]$)'

$output = foreach($line in $csv) {
    if($line.Qty -gt 1) {
        $loopCount = $line.Qty
        $line.Qty  = 1
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $loopCount; $i++) {
            $newLine   = $line.PSObject.Copy()
            $docNumber = $newLine.'Document Number'
            $newLine.'Document Number' = $re.Replace($docNumber, {
                param($s)
                ($i + $s.Groups[1].Value).ToString('D2')
            })
            $newLine
        }
        continue
    }
    $line
}
```

The expected output from the example `$csv` would be:

```
Document Number Qty Price
--------------- --- -----
1111-01         1   3.00
1112-00A        1   4.00
1112-01A        1   4.00
1113-15A        1   5.00
1113-16A        1   5.00
1113-17A        1   5.00
1113-18A        1   5.00
```

Comment: I am getting this data from an excel file. I want to edit the data to have the output as you saw but you are missing vital parts. The document number is getting updated as well as the Qty. I then add to an array because i want to export the data to an excel file. I can easily do what you are showing but the main problem isn't being addressed here.

Comment: @MilanPatel I see what you mean, hopefully the updated code is closer to what you're looking for

Comment: You put expected outcome but have you tested it yourself? I ran this just to see what would happen. Nothing gets outputted to the console.

Comment: @MilanPatel it's all captured in the variable `$output`